# routes in AngularJS and Angular versions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

```
angular.module('appPTracker', ['ui.bootstrap', 
'appPTracker.filters',
'appPTracker.services',
'appPTracker.directives',
'appPTracker.controllers',
'ngGrid']).
config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/main.html', controller: 'ctlPTracker'});
$routeProvider.when('/admin',
    {templateUrl: 'partials/admin.html', controller: 'ctlAdmin'});
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

I have a problem whereby the routing fails ([$injector:modulerr]) if I attempt to use a version above 1.1.4.  Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what needs updating.  I didn't see anything specific to this in the notes...I can provide more source if it's relevant, but it's a pretty generic setup.

Comment: This isn't the answer to your question, I just thought I'd add in that you don't need the route `.when('/'...)` and also have your `otherwise` redirect to it.  Just put the configuration of the route `.when('/'...)` directly in your `otherwise` configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular 1.2 is more modular now. So some parts of it are now an independent piece of code.

`ngRoute` is now one of them.

You need to download it first:

http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-route.js

Load it after angular and then you need to import `ngRoute` like this:

```
angular.module('appPTracker', ['ui.bootstrap', 
'appPTracker.filters',
'appPTracker.services',
'appPTracker.directives',
'appPTracker.controllers',
'ngGrid',
'ngRoute'])
```

Worth saying that there are alternatives to `ngRoute` that worths checking like:

[ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Maybe doesn't work to rework all your routes, but maybe you can check it for a future project :)

Comment: Well that was a simple solution, I was afraid of that :)  I'll check out ui-router, it looks promising, thanks....